# Not able to implement(display) delete for rails 3.2 in HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I am implementing a shopping cart in ruby on rails
The shopping cart has two tables ie shopping list and products.(product references shopping list)
In the shopping list, when I click on the option get products,it is showing me the list of products for the particular shopping list.
There is also an edit and delete button.I have implemented delete in such a way that the if I click on delete the value of delete in database for particular product in database becomes 1(default is zero),but that product is still displayed in the front end (mine is HTML).

ideally i dont want the specific product to be displayed in front end.can you please help me.
my shopping_list controller is as follows:-

```
class ShoppingListsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /shopping_lists
  # GET /shopping_lists.json
  def index
    @shopping_lists = ShoppingList.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @shopping_lists }
    end
  end

  # GET /shopping_lists/1
  # GET /shopping_lists/1.json
  def show
    @shopping_list = ShoppingList.find(params[:id])
    @shopping_list = ShoppingList.includes(:products).find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @shopping_list }
    end
  end

  # GET /shopping_lists/new
  # GET /shopping_lists/new.json
  def new
    @shopping_list = ShoppingList.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @shopping_list }
    end
  end

  # GET /shopping_lists/1/edit
  def edit
    @shopping_list = ShoppingList.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /shopping_lists
  # POST /shopping_lists.json
  def create
    @shopping_list = ShoppingList.new(params[:shopping_list])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @shopping_list.save
        format.html { redirect_to @shopping_list, notice: 'Shopping list was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @shopping_list, status: :created, location: @shopping_list }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @shopping_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def list
   @shopping_lists = ShoppingList.find(:all,
                 :order => "id asc")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :action => 'list' }
      format.json { render :json => @accounts.to_json }
    end       
  end

  # PUT /shopping_lists/1
  # PUT /shopping_lists/1.json
  def update
    @shopping_list = ShoppingList.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @shopping_list.update_attributes(params[:shopping_list])
        format.html { redirect_to @shopping_list, notice: 'Shopping list was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @shopping_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /shopping_lists/1
  # DELETE /shopping_lists/1.json

def delete
    @shopping_list = ShoppingList.find(params[:id])
    @shopping_list.deleted = 1
    @shopping_list.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to shopping_lists_url }
      format.json { render :json => { :success => true } }
  # def destroy
  #  @shopping_list = ShoppingList.find(params[:id])
  # @shopping_list.destroy

  #respond_to do |format|
  # format.html { redirect_to shopping_lists_url }
  #format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def get_product

   @product=Product.where('shopping_list_id = ? ', params[:id])
   # @status=Product.where(status=[[:Open, "open"], [:Close, "close"]])
  # @product_status=Product.where('status = ? ', params[:id])
   # @product=Product.find(params[:shopping_list_id])
   #  @products = Product.includes(:shopping_lists)

  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :action => 'get_products' }
      format.json { render json: @shopping_lists }
    end
 end


 def product_edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end


  def product_delete
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.deleted = 1
    @product.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to shopping_list_url }
      format.json { render :json => { :success => true } }
    end
  end 

  def add_product
    @product = Product.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end

end
```

The Html page I want to display is as follows:-

```
<h1>shopping_list</h1>

shopping_list Id: <%= params[:id] %><br>
shopping_list Name: <%= ShoppingList.where('id = ?', params[:id]).pluck(:shopping_list_name)[0] %><br><br/>

  <table border="1">
 <tr><td>Product id.</td><td>Product Name</td><td>category</td><td>quantity</td><td>status</td><td>Product_edit</td><td>Product_delete</td></tr>
<% @product.each do |p| %>
<tr>
<td>Product id: <%= p.id %> <br></td>
<td>Product name: <%= p.product_name %> <br></td>
<td>Product category: <%= p.product_category %> <br></td>
<td>Product Quantity: <%= p.quantity %> <br></td>
<td>Product status: <%= p.status %>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', {:action => 'product_edit', :id => p.id} %> &nbsp;</td>
<td><%= link_to 'Delete', {:action => 'product_delete', :id => p.id},
    :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this product?" } %></td>
    </tr>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<br/>
<%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list'} %><br/>
<%= link_to 'Add New Products', {:action => 'add_product'} %>
```

Comment: you just said 'displayed in the front end' and then 'not shown in the HTML' - can you clarify?

Comment: When I click on the delete button,the value in the database column'deleted'for products becomes 1 but the product is still displayed.
ideally i dont want the specific product to be displayed in front end.can you please help me.@sevenseacat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can go about this - the best way would be by a scope on your Product model, to filter the products loaded.

A `default_scope where(deleted: 0)` would do the job, but default_scopes can have their own problems (if you want to work with deleted items sometimes, for example).

Comment: Sorry to ask but where should I put default_scope where(deleted: 0),
in def delete? @sevenseacat